# How to Sync Nodes on Private Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, nodes

I have created a Private Ethereum Block chain on AWS with two nodes. One is Primary node and another is Miner. Now I deployed the smart contract on primary node. As its a P2P n/w, same smart contract should be accessible on second node as well, but I am not able to access it from another node.
Also the wallets created in one node are also not accessible in another node. Can any body please enlighten me the process of Syncing the nodes. As I read each node contains the same data of another node.

Comment: What commands do you use in geth to run your nodes?

Comment: @RomanFrolov :
in Node1 i have added the peer (node2 )like below:

admin.addPeer("enode://09884838384d3438438434@176.31.30.106:30301");

then I executed the Geth on Node 2 as below:
geth --datadir ~/eth-dev/ --networkid 4040 --verbosity 3 -ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8546 console